# Identifying another resistor

Tags: resistors

I am working on finding a replacement resistor but am not entirely sure about the code. I am thinking its a 37 Ohm but would like confirmation. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: On top of the resistance, do be aware that that looks like a rather high-power resistor, and should only be replaced with a similarly high-power resistor.

Comment: yeah. its in a 220V circuit. thats also why the varistor is rated at 320V.

Comment: To clarify. I usually do SMD work and am not used to dealing with through hole parts. Currently I am unsure about resistance and rating. I imagine its somewhere between 2 and 4 watts. it would also seem to be a metal oxide resistor and I am unsure if using a 3 watt resistor when a 2 watt one is required would be ok.

Comment: Just asking; why do you think it is a 37 ohm resistor? The color band is charred beyond recognition, and no standard E series for resistor values have a 37 ohm resistor.

Comment: well. the 2nd band seems to be violet and the 3rd is either brown or black which would make very little difference seeing as the Gold on 4 is visible at the top. which would put it at a 37 ohm 4% resistor. Then again I am most certainly wrong. hence the post

Comment: so. I just dug the board back out of the pile and can 100% verify the following. Band 1 is orange, band 3 is black, band 4 is gold and band 5 is yellow. band 2 could be violet or brown. not sure there.

Comment: 2nd band is charred beyond recognition, and yellow does not mean 4% tolerance. Gold means 5% tolerance, and yellow means reliability or temperature coefficient. So as it is only 5% tolerance resistor, and there are only 2 digits before multiplier, standard E series would have 33, 36 or 39 ohms. That is, if the third ring is really black, or just charred beyond recognition.

Comment: Is it actually open or just ratty looking? Maybe you can measure it to get close.

Comment: Had this component **not** failed catastrophically, the pristine aqua printed circuit board surface underneath would be discoloured as well from excess heat. There is also evidence of tiny melted metal  balls embedded in the cracked coating suggesting a quick death. A quick death suggests that other components have failed, causing this one to expire. I'll guess it is open-circuit.